# [iphone]Handle button click on keyboard

Tags: cocoa-touch

Hi how can i get what button is clicked on keyboard.I need to have some kind of listener which get what button is clicked on uiKeyboard.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it, but i think it is one of the ugliest way, but i share my discovery to you.

1.)i made the viewController uitextviewdelegate , and add text view with 0 height and width

2.)i implement the method

`- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`

3.)then i got the value of the last clicked key on keyboard like this

```
foo = textView.text;
textView.text = @"";
```

so this is one way but if you know nicer method for this answer my question :)